# Array values insert into separate documents in mongdb using python in lambda?

Tags: python, mongodb, aws-lambda

I am using python in Lamnda function to execute this code. I have passed two values in event user_id and status.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=1))
community_users = db.community_users

user_id = event['user_id']
status = event['status']

ch2 = [document for document in user_id]
for u_id in ch2:
community_users.insert({ "user_id" : ObjectId(u_id), "status" : 
ObjectId(status)})
return 0
```

Here I have passed status values in array like this.

```
 [5dc4a8b7360a0100012d3ec8, 5dc1f2d14a59120001a4d012, 
  5dc1f2d14a59120001a4d12c, 5dc1f2d14a59120001a4d12c]
```

now I need to store status values as individual documents. I tried 'for' operator but it was stored only array first value. I need output like this below.

```
{ userid: ObjectId("5dc1f2ed4a59120001a4d09d"), status: 
  ObjectId("5dc4a8b7360a0100012d3ec8"}),
{ userid: ObjectId("5dc1f2ed4a59120001a4d09d"), status: 
  ObjectId("5dc1f2d14a59120001a4d012"}),
{ userid: ObjectId("5dc1f2ed4a59120001a4d09d"), status: 
  ObjectId("5dc1f2d14a59120001a4d12c"}),
{ userid: ObjectId("5dc1f2ed4a59120001a4d09d"), status: 
  ObjectId("5dc1f2d14a59120001a4d12c"})
```

Can you please help me out with the answer. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a wrong indentation there. You need to indent the line after the FOR loop:

```
for u_id in ch2:
   community_users.insert({ "user_id" : user_id, "status" : u_id })
```

See [Python indentation](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/statement-indentation-comments)

Comment: I have done the same but array first value only inserted into mongodb.

Comment: it's working. i have write return 0 outside for loop, it's working.